# I want to add CSS for my child class in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, css-selectors, stylesheet, styling

An answer is required in **React Native**.

```
<View>
  <View className="parent1">
    <Text>hello with green</Text>
  </View>
  <View>
    <Text>hello with default color</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

Now I want to add **CSS** to **Text** which has a **parent** whose **classname** is **parent1** in ***React Native***.

Comment: which child class, can you explain little more.

Comment: The text component,whose parent is parent1

Comment: You can't, react-native is really limited about style inheritance. refer to this article: https://medium.com/@fullsour/style-inheritance-of-react-native-eca1c974f02b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you want to give CSS for the text tag which has parent classname as parent1 then follow these steps**:

```
const stylesB = StyleSheet.create(
{

  Text:
  {
    color: '#ffffff',
  },
  p:
  {
    color: '#ffffff',
  },
  h3:
  {
    color: '#ffffff',
  },
  h1:{
    color: '#ffffff',
  }

});

<View>
  <View className="parent1" styles={stylesB}> //give styles as stylesB instead of giving stylesB.Text
    <Text>hello with green</Text>
  </View>
  <View>
    <Text>hello with default color</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

**This change will show color white for children of tag which have classname parent1 and whose tags are Text, p, h1, and h3**.

Comment: I have tried like this but it did not worked for me const mealInfoChildrens = StyleSheet.create({
  Text: { fontWeight: 500, color: "red" }
});  inside render I have something like this <View style={mealInfoChildrens}>
          <Text> {affordability.toUpperCase()}</Text>
          <Text> {complexity.toUpperCase()}</Text>
          <Text> {duration} mins</Text>
        </View>

Comment: @SiluveruKiranKumar replace **style=**  to  **styles=**